# Increase Character speed from a Joystick Input?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, joystick

Now i have a working Joystick, but I want to increase the characters speed.
I´m using this one at the moment: http://roadtonerdvana.wordpress.com/2013/09/20/jcinput-a-simple-joystick-for-sprite-kit/
I attached an Imagefile as the moving object, but it´s way too slow for my purpose.
Where and how can I change the speed?

Comment: What platform does this apply to?  (please update the tags)

Comment: It´s from a sprite kit template.

Comment: Sure, but Sprite Kit and cocos2d is supported under both iOS and OSX, so which platform are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the post you'll know that the joystick returns a x and y value, each ranging from -1 to 1.

*Every time you move the joystick, the properties x and y of it change accordingly, the maximum value is 1 and the minimum is -1.*

In the update method, you could do something like this to adjust the speed :

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    // I'm using the magic number of 5 as an example of how to magnify the speed x5
    float speedX = 5 * self.joystick.x;
    float speedY = 5 * self.joystick.y;

    [self.myLabel setPosition:CGPointMake(self.myLabel.position.x+speedX, self.myLabel.position.y+speedY)];


}
```

Comment: If i insert your lines it says that i use an unused variable "speedX" and "speedY"...

Comment: It won't say that if you modify that 3rd line in the method as I have done.